# App Store still shows download option for Mac OS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I have already installed macOS High Sierra.
[image: About Mac]
But it still shows download option in the App Store.
[image: macOS High Sierra in App Store]

> Also, the some of the new features that High Sierra is providing like Automatic stopping of videos with sound in Safari, was already updated in my system before I even clicked the download button for installing macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download button in App Store is there by design, so you can download a backup copy, a copy for another computer, virtual machine, etc.

Safari 11, the version in High Sierra, is available as a update for Sierra and El Capitan, which enables features like autoplay sound blocking. You probably had auto updates enabled if you don't remember installing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user71659. One more thing!, I heard that Apple released a security patch for High Sierra. However, it is still not available on App Store. So, can I download it from somewhere else?